# Updating tableview without reloading the view (Swift, Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

So I am trying to get all of the favourites from a database to show up in a tableview. However, when I favourite a user, it only displays one.

**The structure of my database looks like:**

```
Favourites:
       UserID:
            key: User 1
            key: User 2
```

and my code:

```
var usersArray[UserClass]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    fetchFavourites()

}

func fetchFavourites () {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let favouriteRef = self.databaseRef.child("favourites").child(userID!)
    favouriteRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let favouriteID = "\(snapshot.value!)"
        let usersRef = self.databaseRef.child("users")

        usersRef.observe(.value, with: { (users) in

            self.usersArray.removeAll()

            for user in users.children {
                let user = UserClass(snapshot: user as! DataSnapshot)

                if favouriteID == user.uid {
                    self.usersArray.append(user)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I have tried creating another array within the function and then making the main array = to that, however it doesn't update the tableview when switching between screens. This code only works when the page view is loaded for the first time. However, I am using a back button that doesn't up date the screen.

Thanks, let me know if you want me to provide anything else.

**Edited code (new problem, see below):**

```
func fetchFavourites () {
    DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        var tempFav = [UserClass]()

        let favouriteRef = self.databaseRef.child("favourites").child(userID!)
        favouriteRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let favouriteID = "\(snapshot.value!)"
            let usersRef = self.databaseRef.child("users")

            tempFav.removeAll()

            usersRef.observe(.value, with: { (users) in

                self.usersArray.removeAll()
                for user in users.children {
                    let user = UserClass(snapshot: user as! DataSnapshot)

                    if favouriteID == user.uid {
                        tempFav.append(user)
                    }
                    self.usersArray = tempFav
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

The problem has been fixed where it populates the tableview with all of the liked users and gets rid of them if I unlike them etc. However, if I unlike all of the users. The array duplicates a user twice even though it should be empty.

Comment: where and how do u call fetchFavourites in your app

Comment: I have updated my code @SandeepBhandari

Comment: "page view is loaded for the first time" do u mean u have your VC as one of the viewController in UIPageViewController ??

Comment: insert or delete rows in between beginupdate and endupdate methods of tableview

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Sorry I meant Table view

Comment: @SandeepBhandari See the edited code, thanks